# Find who uses a symbol in an ELF file

Tags: c, linux, elf, linkage

I have a big binary, that contains a symbol. I can see the symbol in `nm` or `objdump`.
I know that the symbol is used, because otherwise the linker wouldn't include it (more precisely, I know that some symbol in the same source file is used).
I'm trying to find how exactly it's used.

If the reference is by a function (e.g. function calling a function, function using global variatble), I can use `objdump -rd` to disassemble the file and find the reference.
But if the reference is by a variable (e.g. a global pointer initialized to point to some variable), disassembly doesn't show it.
I failed to find any method that does.

Here's an example that demonstrates it. In this example it's obvious who uses `x`, but I don't know how to examine the resulting binary and find it.

```
// x.c
int x = 3;

// main.c
extern int x;
static int *y = &x;
int main() { 
    return *y;
}

// Build process
gcc -o x.o -c x.c
ar r libx.a x.o
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o main main.o -L. -lx
```

Comment: `main.o` will have a relocation entry in the data section for x. Let me reproduce and show the exact wordings.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled the same code (and same commands) and ran `objdump -x main.o`. There is a section

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.data]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000000 R_X86_64_64       x
```

Which means it is a 64 bit relocation record(`R_X86_64_64`). It is at offset 0 in the data section (this is the offset of y in the data section). And the value to be relocated is `x` (which is actually the address of the variable `x`, since it is the label).

To understand this better I added another variable -

```
extern int ** z = &y;
```

Now the symbol table looks like -

```
0000000000000000 l     O .data  0000000000000008 y
0000000000000008 l     O .data  0000000000000008 z
```

The first shows the offset of both the variables in the data section and the second number is their sizes.

The relocation table also now looks like -

```
0000000000000000 R_X86_64_64       x
0000000000000008 R_X86_64_64       .data
```

You can see that there are two entries now. One for `x`'s address being stored in `y` (offset 0) and the other is for `y`'s address being stored in `z` (offset 8). Instead of `y` you see `.data` because the address of the data section is the same as the address of `y` because `y` is at offset `0`.

Thus by looking at the relocation table, you can find the absolute references of all variables (or functions).

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to find it by inspecting the binary `main` alone? Recreating the intermediate files isn't always simple.

Comment: @ugoren the same relocation table exists for the executable too. Since these are 64 bit references.

Comment: Although some names might have disappeared if the binary is stripped

Comment: The relocation entries don't exist in `main`. I didn't strip it - I compiled exactly as in my question.

Comment: @ugoren oh, that is because the gcc linker discards the relocation table, because executables are usually non relocatable. i.e. they are always executed at the same address. You can link (your last command) as `gcc -Wl,-q ...` to instruct `gcc` to keep the relocation table.

Comment: @ugoren If you cannot control how the binaries are linked, there is not much to do other than searching for the address of the variables (like in your answer). But as you guesses that wouldn't always work.

Comment: @ugoren relocation table is also kept by default if you make a shared library.

Comment: I did eventually find it, by adding trace flags to the link command. The reference to the variable actually wasn't in the binary - it was in a shared library it was linked with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I found. It works for this simple example, but unfortunately not for my real case. I'm not sure what's the difference.

I'm looking for users of symbol `x` in binary `main`:

```
$ objdump -t main | grep -w x
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              x.c
0000000000601040 g     O .data  0000000000000004              x
```

So x is in offset `00601040`. I look for this address, reversed (because of endianity, I guess):

```
$ objdump -s main | egrep '^Contents of section|40106000'
... omitted irrelevant sections ...
Contents of section .data:
 601028 00000000 00000000 40106000 00000000  ........@.`.....
```

So the symbol at offset `601030` in `.data` contains this address.

```
$ objdump -t main | grep 601030
0000000000601030 g     O .data  0000000000000008              y
```

So the reference is from `y`

In my real case, the address is found in the `.dynsym` section, and `objdump -t` doesn't find any symbols there.